# Notepad++ Column Editing Fit Multiline Uneven Width Selection In a Single Character Column Selection

Tags: notepad++, text-processing

I couldn't find a question which is answering my exact problem even if there are many questions with similar headline.

When I am using Notepad++ in a column editing mode (alt + shift + drag to select + c to copy) and I select multiple lines with uneven widht and I try to paste it into the same number of rows selection it doesn't place the text into the borders I have selected as a column.

Example text to copy in colum editing mode:

[image: image alt-text]

Example column editing mode selection in which I want the selection from the above example to be pasted in:

[image: image alt-text]

Output:

[image: image alt-text]

Desired output:

[image: image alt-text]

Comment: Please inline your screenshots using the syntax [![image alt-text][#]][1] ([once you have sufficient rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252370)).

Comment: I'd suggest updating the title of your question to something along the lines of "How to append to a region selection"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only *prepend* region-selected text data unless your text is all equal length. My workaround to *appending* to unaligned text is to

1. `Cut` the preexisting text **using a region-selection** (and watch out for trailing whitespace):

[image]

2. Type the characters you wish to append (your should still have the region selected, so just type them):

[image]

3. *Re*-region-select where you cut your text from and `Paste` your text back:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That information has helped me to understand my issue better and solved it along with it. It appears that if you press alt followed by shit but you move your arrow in a diagonal direction and not sideways you may create once in a while a shape that is not proper which can't be pasted properly.

Comment: It looks like your issue was selecting all the text *normally* instead of a region, probably because of how you expanded the selection using arrow keys (I just use the mouse (even tho I strongly prefer the keyboard for everything you can), otherwise you're doing a bunch of toggling `shift` `ctrl` and `alt` keys in weird ways).
So when you paste a normal selection of text (rather than a region) in a region selection, it will interleave it with each source line in the region selection.